# iTunes Store Operation failed - the app references non-public

Tags: ios, ipad

i've an issue submitting an app on apple.
The error is:

iTunes Store operation failed.
Te App references non-public sellectors in Payload/aaaa.app/aaaa:
createEntity, defaultContext, elementWithName:

can you help me in understand what i must to do for resolve it?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Is it just a a warning or an error? Are you using mogenerator? If it's just a warning you can most likely ignore it as it's iTC over compensating

Comment: Yes, I'm using mogenerator and Magical Record. It's a warning so I'm ignoring it now.